# Is there a clear, definitive explanation for what happened in Evangelion 3.33?

Tags: anime, evangelion

I'm hoping this isn't too opinion based, but I completely lost track of the narrative in the newly released (US at least) Evangelion 3.33.

I followed 1 and 2 well enough, but I'm trying to figure out:

1) Is there an actual explanation for what happened in 3.33 or
2) Did the narrative fall apart to such a degree that there is no coherent explanation or
3) Is this supposed to be this way because there's a fourth film underway?

I know Evangelion lore can often defy scrutiny, but there always seemed to be a visible arc or through line in the narrative that became so obtuse in this release that I'm at a total loss for even a basic summary.

Maybe I can further explain with the following points that are lost on me:

- The Vessel of the Adams is...
- It was originally part of the Wunder?
- Kaworu Nagisa, who seemed to be on the moon in part 1, is now a part
  of what used to be Nerv and is...?
- Was Kaworu tricked into tricking Shinji into starting the 4th impact? Which happened because he's an angel and removed spears that weren't the right spears from a Lilith that wasn't a Lilith and..

Sigh.

Comment: This new 4-movie series is a remake with a different take on the events portrayed in the original series/movies, so we have yet to see how it all fits together, hopefully in the fourth and last movie. I'm afraid it's not revealed yet.

Comment: Yes, what happened is that a bunch of weird crap occurred, then everyone pretended to understand what was happening.

Comment: Oh. I thought this would be a question about what happened somewhere in the Bible…

Comment: Every time they try to end Evangelion they invariably try to be more.... um... artistic? It's almost like they're just trolling at this point. In another 10 years they'll make another End of EVA movie and it'll feature people throwing potatoes at a disco ball and some barely coherent mumblings regarding angels. Then a big fluorescent sign will illuminate that reads "everyone died", accompanied by a looping soundtrack of 5 people sighing.

Comment: I'm still laughing at your desire to get a "coherent explanation" as to what is happening in Evangelion. Good luck with that, let me know how you get on.

Comment: Hahah @GorchestopherH